# pg_trgm, similarity and finding duplicate questions by their answers

Tags: postgresql, duplicates, similarity, postgresql-9.6, pg-trgm

I have a table named `Questions`.  It has the `content` field (which contains a question) and an `answer` field.  The whole table has around 22k rows and I'm trying to figure out how to search for duplicate questions based on common answers (although I'm open to suggestions on a better way).

Basically I'd like to figure out a way to find possible duplicate rows within some range of probability.

Eg I have 132 answers which have more than 5 questions related to them.  How could I go about comparing these questions to weed out possible duplicates?  Could I use something like `similarity` to compare all of the questions by grouped `answers`?  I'm just not quite sure how this would work or if there's a better way for tracking these down.

```
SELECT LOWER(questions.answer) AS answer, count(*) AS same_answer, array_agg(questions.content), array_agg(questions.id)
FROM questions
WHERE questions.answer IS NOT null
AND LOWER(questions.answer) <> 'true'
AND LOWER(questions.answer) <> 'false'
GROUP BY LOWER(questions.answer)
HAVING count(*) > 5
ORDER BY count(*) DESC
```

Any pointers or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.